# Конвертация java в Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Пишу приложение по статье, но только на Kotline

```
public class HeadLineViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private static final MutableLiveData MUTABLE_LIVE_DATA = new MutableLiveData();
{
       MUTABLE_LIVE_DATA.setValue(null);
}
public final ObservableField<NewsResponse> project = new ObservableField<>();

    public HeadLineViewModel(@NonNull HeadLineRepository headLineRepository,
    @NonNull Application application) 
{
super(application);
newsResponseObservable = HeadLineRepository.getInstance()
.getHeadLine("in","84a7decf3110498ea372bd16dd0601e8");
    }

    public LiveData<NewsResponse> getNewsResponseObservable()
    {
        return newsResponseObservable;
    }
}
```

Меня интересует вот эта строчка:

```
public final ObservableField<NewsResponse> project = new ObservableField<>();
```

Я бы ее использовал так:

```
var project: ObservableField<NewsResponse> = ObservableField<>()
```

Но такой конструкции в Kotlin нету, кто может помочь с поиском аналога?

Возможна нужна какая-то библиотека (в статье не показаны, что за библиотеки), и ссылки на github нету
[Статья](https://medium.com/@amtechnovation/android-architecture-component-mvvm-part-1-a2e7cff07a76)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField, https://github.com/googlesamples/android-databinding - примеры на kotlin

Comment: @iFr0z спасибо конечно, но достаточно было просто указать что это библиотека databinding

Comment: 4 символов не хватало

Comment: все равно спасибо

Comment: еще супер маленькая ремарка, если у тебя на java - final, то на котлине val (заместо var)

Comment: хорошо, спасибо